# inverse of an element in semi group makes identity

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am studying some points in semi groups. my question is: can we treat $aa^{-1}$ in an inverse semigroup as I treat $aa^{-1}$ in a group (identity)? I see the book write $(aa^{-1})b=b$ so this idea gets to mind that if a has an inverse in an inverse semigroup then we can omit $aa^{-1}$ wherever I see this word. Thank you...

Comment: What would $a^{-1}$ mean if not "the element such that $aa^{-1}$ is the identity"?

Comment: That's right. I assume the semigroup is monoid. someone to my head tells this is right that aa^-1 works as 1 but I am not sure. Obsession...

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing, an inverse semigroup with identity element, is called an inverse monoid. Inverse monoids are not necesarily groups, and $aa^{-1}$ is not necessarily the identity element. It is, however, necessarily idempotent (i.e. $(aa^{-1})^2 = aa^{-1}$). This follows immediately from $aa^{-1}a = a$. Also, if the inverse monoid is cancellative (i.e. $ab = ac\implies b = c$ and $ac = bc\implies a = b$), then it is necessarily a group.

**Example:** take a non-empty set $X$, and let $M$ be the set of all bijections from subsets of $X$ to subsets of $X$. Then partial function composition (compose functions wherever possible, restrict domains where composition is not possible) gives $M$ an inverse monoid structure, and it is called the *symmetric inverse monoid* on $X$. The identity element is the identity function on all of $X$, and the inverse of any element is its standard inverse function.

Here $aa^{-1}$ is the identity function *on the domain of $a^{-1}$*, while $a^{-1}a$ is the identity function *on the domain of $a$*. These are not the identity functions on all of $X$.

Comment: Clifford in his book said: If S denotes an inverse semigroup then an element "a" has a unique inverse "a^-1" so "aa^-1a=a". My question is if the semigroup has 1, can we say that "aa^-1" works as 1 or  not?

Comment: @Gozal I have revised my post. Is this more the kind of answer you were looking for?

Comment: Thank you friend! I got it. Sorry for the delay in response.